# Php Problem with move_uploaded_file. It seems everything is fine but it is not working

Tags: php

I am trying to use `move_uploaded_file` but I think everything is fine but my code is not working. Everything is working as expected even image name is being inserted into DB but it is not moving into uploads folder. Folder is there and apache2 does have access to write it.

I don't have enough reputation to post more then 8 lines so everything is on pastebin Here. The main aprt is...

```
 $post_image_new_name = uniqid('', true). "." 
.$post_image_actual_ext;

                $post_image_destination = '../../uploads/';
                    if (is_dir($post_image_destination) && is_writable($post_image_destination)) {

                    $post_image_destination = '../../uploads/'.$post_image_new_name;
                    var_dump($post_image_destination);
                    move_uploaded_file($post_image_new_name, $post_image_destination);
                    echo "Inside move_uploaded_file section";
```

https://pastebin.com/Z321R76z

Comment: Hint: `move_uploaded_file()` expects the source filename of the uploaded file. It is usually member `$_FILES[...]->tmp_name`.

Comment: ***Warning*** Please validate Formats before placing them in your directory, any attacker can use this way to upload any type of file. See https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat/

Comment: Thanks dude 
I didn't knew such an attack is possible and yes you are right
I am a new learner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code
line 53: `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['addPost_post_image']['tmp_name'], $post_image_destination);`

The first param should be the file source name.

Comment: Thanks brother it has been solved. The problem is as you said it to be. I would love to add a plus but I lack reputation to do so :)

Comment: Thank you @MahadAli

Comment: Can you upvote my post? lol I got banned from posting question :D

Answer (score 1):

`move_uploaded_file()` expects the source filename of the uploaded file. So you must use something like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['addPost_post_image']['tmp_name'], $post_image_destination);
```